# About twitter API

Tags: api, twitter, oauth

I want to use the twitter API function.
After the user authorization, it will automatically follow my account.
Authorization has been completed,but it cannot be tracked automatically.
I can't find the API file.
Which api file correspond to this function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want `statuses/home_timeline` documented here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-home_timeline.html